# How to build a wrapper around scalatest's "it" keyword?

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalactic

I am attempting to build a wrapper around [scalatest](http://www.scalatest.org)'s `it` keyword. However, this solution does not seem to work as intended. Moreover, it does not even compile:

```
trait MyFunSpec extends FunSpec {

  private val _it: FunSpec.this.ItWord = it

  protected def it(specText: String, testTags: org.scalatest.Tag*)
    // ...do something extra here...
    (testFun: => Any /* Assertion */)(implicit pos: Position): Unit = {
    _it(specText, testTags: _*)(testFun)(pos)
    // ...do something extra here...
  }
}
```

The error message I am getting after compiling this code is as follows:

```
[error] MyFunSpec.scala: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
[error] both method it in trait MyFunSpec of type (specText: String, testTags:
  org.scalatest.Tag*)(testFun: => Any)(implicit pos:
  org.scalactic.source.Position)Unit
[error] and value it in trait FunSpecLike of type => FunSpecSpec.this.ItWord
[error] match argument types (String)
```

Please note the main idea is that method's name remains `it`, so renaming it to something like `alternativeIt` is not a satisfactory solution here.

Any suggestions, what am I doing wrong here? Any solution would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: When you try to alias it to _it, the compiler gets confused because there's a definition if it in FunSpecLike and another one in MyTrait (therefore it is overloaded). Second, in order to really override it, you should actually override val it = new ItWord { ... }. Inside that anonymous class super references the old ItWord implementation in FunSpec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
trait MyFunSpec extends FunSpec {
  override protected val it = new ItWord {
    override def apply(specText: String,testTags: org.scalatest.Tag*)(testFun: => Any)(implicit pos: org.scalactic.source.Position): Unit = {
      println("Before")
      super.apply(specText, testTags:_*)(testFun)(pos)
      println("After")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A few words to explain your solution would be nice. The OP also asked what was wrong with their own code.